# What do you call a heterosexual who wonders what it would be like to have a relationship with a gay person?

Tags: single-word-requests, sexual-minorities

In "Perfect Zen" by E. A. St. Amant it is written:

> “You're a breeder voyeur,” Paulo remarked. “She loves the explicit gay
>   porno stuff, like at the Barn.”

I found that a *[breeder voyeur](http://wordspy.com/words/breedervoyeur.asp)* is  'A heterosexual person who attends a gay bar or event in order to observe gay life', so, I'm wondering what do you call a heterosexual who, not only observes gay life, but wonders what it would be like to live and to have a relationship with a gay person.

The first word that come to my mind is *curious*, but it seems too general and I'm looking for a word that fits more precisely that meaning.

Comment: My favourite for this is "3-beer-queer".

Comment: Your question is a little vague. It is rather like asking for a word that describes someone who wonders what it is like to be a soldier. Why should there be such a word? Most people have wondered what it would be like to have a different sexual orientation at some time in their lives -- some with a sense of intrigue and some, no doubt, with a sense of revulsion.  Just imagining something doesn't really warrant a word in my opinion.

Answer (score 17):

The word is ***bicurious*** (often hyphenated, *bi-curious*). There's also *homoflexible* and *heteroflexible*.

> *Bi-curious* is a term used to refer to people of a heterosexual or homosexual identity who, while showing some curiosity for a relationship or sexual activity with a person of the sex they do not favor, distinguish themselves from the bisexual label. The term is sometimes used to describe a broad continuum of sexual orientation between heterosexuality and bisexuality.
>
> The terms *heteroflexible* and *homoflexible* are also applied to bi-curiosity, though some authors distinguish heteroflexibility as lacking the "wish to experiment with ... sexuality" implied by the bi-curious label.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicurious)

Comment: Bi-curious suggests that a heterosexual is imagining sex with a homosexual and being aroused. The question doesn't necessarily suggest that the heterosexual is thinking of this because he desires to have sex with a man. He may be thinking about it an abstract sense.

Answer (score -1):

**Inhibited**  Oxford Dictionary defines one as unable to act in a relaxed and natural way because of self-consciousness or mental restraint.  I would add also due to Societal Constraints (laws), Religious Convictions, and Social Norms.